# Windows installer strange custom actions

Tags: windows-installer, custom-action

I'm exploring the MSI custom-actions, I'm using ORCA to see what is the actual MSIs contains.

I found in one MSI the following action types for example : `3073`, `1537` and many other [CustomAction](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa368066%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)s types that I couldn't find any resource that have a full index for those various types.

Is there for example a way that I can create an customized CustomAction types, or maybe the new version of Windows Installer CustomActions not documented yet ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Read [Custom Action Types](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa372048%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) and adjacent help topics.

3073 = 2048 | 1024 | 1

1= DLL file stored in a Binary table stream.
1024 = msidbCustomActionTypeInScript Queues for execution at scheduled point within script. This flag designates that this is a deferred execution custom action.
2048 = msidbCustomActionTypeNoImpersonate Queues for execution at scheduled point within script. Executes with no user impersonation. Runs in system context.

Comment: I got it, I thought that the `CustomAction` type is only a number without the flags you talk about. Thank you very much.